# Is it possible to send off info row by row from Access to QuickBooks?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

Currently I have the following code that allows me to insert values into specific fields in QuickBooks.

I am trying to add fields from a table into QuickBooks row by row:
See picture ex:

Example:

[image]

At the end of each row there is a column for sending off the entries to QuickBooks. How can I modify my code to have this function work?

```
Public Sub exampleInsert()
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3

Dim oConnection
Dim oRecordset
Dim sMsg
Dim sConnectString
Dim sSQL

sConnectString = "DSN=Quickbooks Data;OLE DB Services=-2;"
sSQL = "Insert into customer (Name, FullName, CompanyName) values ('Testing VB', 'Full Name', 'Test Company Name')"
Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oConnection.Open sConnectString
oConnection.Execute (sSQL)
sMsg = sMsg & "Record Added"
MsgBox sMsg


Set oRecordset = Nothing
Set oConnection = Nothing
End Sub
```

UPDATE:

I added:

```
sConnectString = "DSN=Quickbooks Data;OLE DB Services=-2;"
sSQL = "Insert into customer (Name, CompanyName) Select Num, Description From TestTable"
Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
oConnection.Open sConnectString
oConnection.Execute (sSQL)
sMsg = sMsg & "Record Added"
MsgBox sMsg
```

But I get the error "Invalid table name: TestTable" how can I get this SQL script to see my Access table?

Comment: Does your code work now (in that the hard-coded values are sent to QuickBooks)? If so, you'll just have to update your query to add in your form values.

Comment: What can I add to my code to add info from my form values?

Comment: Ok I have added some things, but now I am getting an error. Can you take a look?

Comment: Why not use [linked tables](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-another-access-database-095ab408-89c7-45b3-aac2-58036e45fcf6) with your OLE DB Quickbooks DSN?

Answer (score 0):

To add the form's current record values to your queries, you just pull the value (e.g. `Me.txtDescription`). I would recommend you use the `ADODB.Command` object, so you can parameterize your SQL and avoid SQL injection:

```
Option Explicit

Const adOpenStatic As Integer = 3
Const adLockOptimistic As Integer = 3
Const CONNECTION_STRING As String = "DSN=Quickbooks Data;OLE DB Services=-2;"

Private Sub Command10_Click()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim param As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim sMsg As String

    ' set up ADODOB connection
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Open CONNECTION_STRING 

    ' set up ADODB command object
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

    ' note that we're using unnamed parameters,
    ' with the ? symbol
    cmd.CommandText = _
            "INSERT INTO customer " & _
            "(Name, CompanyName) " & _
            "VALUES " & _
            "(?, ?)"

    ' add form values as command parameters
    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter( _
            Type:=adVarChar, _
            Size:=255, _
            value:=Me.txtNumber)

    cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter( _
            Type:=adVarChar, _
            Size:=255, _
            value:=Me.txtDescription)

    ' now that we have the command set up with its params,
    ' we can just execute it:
    cmd.Execute

    sMsg = "Record Added"
    MsgBox sMsg

    Set param = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    cn.Close: Set cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Of course, you'll have to use the actual names of your textboxes.

Also, please notice a couple of additional modifications I a made to your original code:

- I have `Option Explicit` defined. You may already have this in your code, but if not, you need it. That way, any variables used have to be declared. For more information, see the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement)
- I moved your `ADODB` constants outside your sub. Ideally, you'd either use early binding and add the ADODB library reference (so you don't need to define these yourself), or add them in a separate module, so you can use them in any of your forms.
- I also added your connection string as a constant outside your sub. Again, this should probably be in a separate module (e.g. `modConstants`) you can easily refer to from anywhere in your project.
- I improved the indentation of your code.
- I explicitly added the types for your declarations (`Dim sSQL as String` rather than just `Dim sSQL`). Note that if you declare a variable without a type, it defaults to the `Variant` type, instead of `String` (which you want). See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/declaring-variables) for more information.

Comment: Now I get the error Compile error: User-defined type not defined

Comment: @Daniel: You'll have to [add the ADODB references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/using-ado-with-microsoft-visual-basic?view=sql-server-2017) (or switch to late binding)

Comment: I have defined the ADODB reference but I am now receiving the same error with  cn.Open sConnectString being highlighted

Comment: @Daniel: Is your `sConnectstring` defined as a string, or as a variant (i.e. `Dim sConnectionString`, with no type)?

Comment: I updated my answer: If you changed to the `CONNECTION_STRING` constant, you'll have to use that: `cn.Open CONNECTION_STRING`

Comment: Now it is saying the same thing but highlighting cmd.ActiveConnection = oConnection

Comment: updated my answer again: You need to use the new `cn` object, rather than `oConnection`.

Comment: So now its giving me an error for using Me.txtDescription - I've tried changing "Me" to the tables name in Access, but then it tells me that it is not defined.

Comment: I think we are very close here, any suggestions?

Comment: The `Me` refers to the form: You need to change `txtDescription` to whatever your actual text box is named.

Comment: I am not using a form @Zack I am only using a table

Comment: I am not referring to textboxes just rows and columns

Comment: This action really needs to be handled on a form: I would suggest you create a new form tied to the table, and put your code there.